# I can find() but I can't save(), why?

Tags: php, sqlite, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP with SQLite3 DB in Windows 7 x64 with PHP 5.3.8. I've a controller and when do a find("all") the records are retrieved but when I try to save() nothing hapens also when I try to read() and not understand where the problem is. This the code: http://pastebin.com/VNYSh5j3, can any help me to find where the problem is?

Comment: Are you talking about `crear()` or `editar()`?

Comment: Both the save() method in crear() doesn't work and the read() method in editar() doesn't work too

Comment: Do you know if the call to `save()` is actually reached?

Comment: Well the code die with "Entro" so I think it's reached anyway how can I check if it reached or not? I'm newbie with CakePHP

Comment: I don't see `Entro` anywhere. To see how it behaves, you could add a `echo "I got this far";` right before the calls to `save()`. If you see it when you run your script, it got there.

Comment: See I updated the code at http://pastebin.com/btwg3pWu but as I said before die("Entro") works but save($this->data) and create() didn't

Comment: put a debug($this->data) before die(), and set debug level to 2. you could check if the array structure is all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not getting any PHP errors, you should check file permissions.

Both your SQLite database file *and the directory enclosing it* must be writable by PHP. Just having the file be writable is not enough.